# Property label not found on String and there is no default value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Based on the following data

```
public var dataArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
    { label: "None", data: '' },
    { label: "Some Data", data: 
        { 
            label: "String tested at IF", data: "20"
        }
    }
]);
```

I then create a new ArrayCollection obj based on the position a user has selected from a dropdown list

```
var skillArrayCollection:ArrayCollection  = ArrayCollection(runtimeComponents[dataArray[classSelect.selectedIndex].data]);
```

I am looping through an ArrayCollection object like so:

```
  for each (var item:Object in skillArrayCollection[charSkillOne.selectedIndex]) { 
        if (item.label == "somelabel") {
           ret = ret + Number(item.data);
          }
  }
```

When the if statement does its check 'it matches the string test and returns the correct result; IT also returns the error: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property label not found on String and there is no default value.

I do not understand how flex will error and return the result i have asked for?

Comment: How can the if statement return an error while also returning a valid result?  If 'item' is a String, then a String does not have a label property and that is why you get the error.  Please expand on what you mean.

Comment: Hi, Item can not be a string surly? it is a object of a array position and I am asking if the value of the label key from a arraycollection matches a value i give it, which in this case it does as well as errorin :s

Comment: We don't know what's in `runtimeComponents`, so we can't tell. But the VM is telling you that item is a String, so I would tend to believe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first object here:

```
{ label: "None", data: '' },
{ label: "Some Data", data: 
    { 
        label: "String tested at IF", data: "20"
    }
}
```

data is a string, in your second object, data is an object with a label property.

When your loop goes through each element there the first would cause this error because when you call object.data.label on it you're trying to get a label property of a string, hence the error (for the second object if it were to get there it would not error).  As others state the question leaves out the contents of runtimeComponents so it's difficult to say this is for sure the issue but it seems right.